# play all video types in one browser - using any way possible

Tags: javascript, html, video, plugins, codec

I have a problem that most the internet has with html 5 videos. There is no way to play all video types in any one browser. You need to include many different formats to make sure that my browser can play any video type. This is a big problem that one of my clients has, and he has pushed to me.

I can only read from the server to get the videos, and there is only one version of any video on the server. The person running the server has refused to convert any videos before saving to the server, and people upload their videos to this server from any type of device, and as such there are about 7 different formats. No browser supports all 7. I need some way, and I mean ***any*** way to be able to stream these videos in real time from the web.

I have found ways to convert them in javascript, but it takes like 2 minutes to convert a 30 second video. I have tried adding plugins, but I have not found any plugin that can do it. My current thought, and I am testing this: use Explorer and windows media player to play videos, or use quicktime with safari to play the videos.

Maybe there is some magical plugin that can play all video MIME types, like VLC, but VLC is no longer supported for some reason in chrome, and I cannot find it in fire fox. or maybe I can add the codec to Chrome or firefox? Maybe draw the video on a canvas, and stream audio magically? or sacrifice my first born son? heck i'll even throw in the second kid.

If someone can help me I would be so happy, and I think a lot of the internet would be too.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for an offsite source which makes this question off topic here.

Comment: Why won't the server-side software convert the video? This sounds like laziness on their part.

Comment: it is laziness on their part, but it has been pushed to me to solve kinda like multi threading hardware/software issue

Comment: @Charlie-Fish what do you mean offsite source?

Comment: first question - what is the format that the lazy site operator does have

Comment: people upload to the server from their devices, it is not the server provider that dictates the format. So the format is any format that you can get from recording from a camera.

Comment: @SamuelThompson I recommend reading the help center. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #4 here, "Maybe there is some magical plugin"

Comment: any solution???

Comment: no it is not possible with a pure front end solution.